# How to overwrite a parameter from the configfile that is not at the first level in a snakemake call?

Tags: snakemake

I can't figure out the syntax. For example:

```
snakemake --configfile myconfig.yml --config myparam="new value"
```

This will overwrite the value of `config["myparam"]` from the yaml file upon workflow execution.

But what if I want to overwrite `config["myparam"]["otherparam"]`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. A general remark: Note that --config should be used as little as possible, because it defeats the goal of reproducibility and data provenance (you would have to remember the command line with which you invoked snakemake).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't usually use that parameter for I put everything in the configfile, but I wanted to use it exceptionally in a kind of teaching way, in order to show how to alter a workflow without having to put one's hands dirty.

Comment: I've noticed that when using the --config parameters has an effect on the rules invoked, this change doesn't seem to appear in the dag and rulegraph, is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: Nope. This is surprising. Could you open an issue with a minimal example?

Comment: My bad, it actually comes from the way I generate flowcharts by using a rule - in which obviously the --config parameter used in the commandline doesn't apply. I need to think of another way to deal with this. Thank you for your time